# AttributeError: module 'discord.ui' has no attribute 'ActionRow'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

**What i'm making**

I am adding a feature to my discord bot that allows you to pin and unpin messages with :pushpin:. When you unpin a message, the bot sends a message saying that a message has been unpinned.

**My code**

```py
# Pin feature
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.emoji.name == "":
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        await message.pin()
    print("Reaction added.")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.emoji.name == "":
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        pins = [reaction for reaction in message.reactions if str(reaction.emoji) == ""]
        if len(pins) == 0:
            await message.unpin()
            button = discord.ui.Button(label="View Unpinned Message", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="view_unpinned_message")
            async def send_message(ctx: discord.Interaction):
                await ctx.channel.send(content=message.content)
            button.callback = send_message
            view_message_action_row = discord.ui.ActionRow(button)
            await channel.send("A previously pinned message has been unpinned.", components=[view_message_action_row])
    print("A reaction has been removed.")
```

I want it so that there is a button that is under the "pinned message has been unpinned" message that redirects you to the message that was unpinned.

**The error**

If i remove all the code that makes the button pop up, the message appears.
I want the button to be there though, but with what i'm using, the message doesn't pop up at all and gives me this error:

```
2023-04-11 00:16:30 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tar.py", line 45, in on_raw_reaction_remove
    view_message_action_row = discord.ui.ActionRow(button)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'discord.ui' has no attribute 'ActionRow'
```

**What I tried**

Some of the things first things i've tried are updating my python version (now 3.11) and my discord.py version (now 2.2.2). Same problem.

I've also found that something called "discord-components" once worked.
Tried downloading it using pip3 install discord-components, but it did nothing. I heard that discord.py supports buttons on it's own anyway so I guess it wouldn't have helped either way.

**Full code**

Don't know if this is gonna help anyone, but just in case, here is the bot's entire code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# boring

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

THRESHOLD = 5

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(1069346031281651843)
# Used to make announcements in server, disabled atm (should prob make it more efficient)
#    await channel.send('', file=discord.File(''))
    print('All systems go!'.format(bot))

# Pin feature
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.emoji.name == "":
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        await message.pin()
    print("Reaction added.")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.emoji.name == "":
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        pins = [reaction for reaction in message.reactions if str(reaction.emoji) == ""]
        if len(pins) == 0:
            await message.unpin()
            button = discord.ui.Button(label="View Unpinned Message", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="view_unpinned_message")
            async def send_message(ctx: discord.Interaction):
                await ctx.channel.send(content=message.content)
            button.callback = send_message
            view_message_action_row = discord.ui.ActionRow(button)
            await channel.send("A previously pinned message has been unpinned.", components=[view_message_action_row])
    print("A reaction has been removed.")

# api token

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionRow` is located in discord, though if you're wanting to add a button, its better to create a class for it.

UnpinButton, your main button:

```py
class UnpinButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__()

        self.message = message

    @discord.ui.button(label="View Unpinned Message", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, emoji="")
    async def button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(self.message.content)
```

After your class, just replace the previous ActionRow message with your new button:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.emoji.name == "":
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        pins = [reaction for reaction in message.reactions if str(reaction.emoji) == ""]

        if len(pins) == 0:
            if message.pinned:
                await message.unpin()

                Unpinned = UnpinButton(message)
            
                await channel.send("A previously pinned message has been unpinned.", view=Unpinned)

    print("A reaction has been removed.")
```

The full documentation is here: [Discord.ActionRow Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ActionRow)

Comment: This is the error that I get now

```line 40, in on_raw_reaction_remove
    view_message_action_row = discord.ActionRow(button) # < Edit
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: @stellarstye I updated the answer with better code

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much!
(Also thanks for making it convenient for me and not making it like some others here who make the answer sound super complicated)